# Regular Expression issue

Tags: php, regex, replace, match

I have the following URL structure which I need to match to and get the particular id from:

```
/group/subgroup/id-name
```

In short, I need to translate a URL like the following:

```
/Blue Products/Dark Blue/5-Blue_Jelly
```

To:

```
/?pagename=Blue Products&model=5
```

**IMPORTANT:** I don't need to match `group`, I already have group.

Example code:

```
<?php

    foreach($cats as $cat)
        $cmd->rewrite('/\/'.$cat.'\/unused\/(ID)-unused\//','/?pagename='.$cat.'&model=%ID%');

?>
```

---

**Edit:**

This is the completed code:

```
    if($groups->count()){

        $names=array();
        foreach($groups->rows as $row)
            $names[]=preg_quote($row->group);
        $names=implode('|',$names);

        $regex='('.$names.')/([^/]+)/([0-9]{1,})-([^/]+)/?$';

        CmsHost::cms()->rewrite_url($regex,'index.php?pagename=Products',true);
    }
```

Comment: Isn't regexp a bit overkill for this... Why not simply explode the "url string" on / and then just look at the individual elements of the resultant array?

Comment: @Mark Baker - I try avoiding regexp at all costs, but in this case, that rewrite method only accepts a regular expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\d+` to match **d**ecimals.

```
$cmd->rewrite("#/$cat/.+?/(\d+)-.*?/#', ...
```

Use `#` as outer delimiters to avoid extraneous escaping of `\/`

Answer (score 1):

Why use regex when you can use simple string functions like so:

```
$parts = explode('/', trim('/Blue Products/Dark Blue/5-Blue_Jelly', '/'));
list($group, $subgroup, $id_name) = $parts;
```

Comment: Agreed, but he is trying to get the ID, whereas this will give him the ID-name -- which admittedly isn't a huge obstacle to overcome. :)

Comment: A simple string function for that would be `strtok` or `strrchr`. Using `explode` for micro optimization purposes is less resilient to invalid formats, and here's the fun fact: *slower* due to the array workaround.

Comment: Same as I replied to Mr Baker above; the regex serves two purposes: **1** check if the URL matches my pattern and **2** (optionally) find parts I need to form the new url.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$url = preg_replace("'/".$cat."/[^/]+/([0-9]+)-.*'i","/?pagename=".$cat."&model=\\1",$url);
```

Hope this works!